# SQL - Get result in fractional format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table which contains data as follows -

```
MinFormat(int)  MaxFormat(int)  Precision(nvarchar)
  -2              3             1/2
```

Now i want result from SP as  -

```
 -2
 -3/2 
 -1 
 -1/2 
  0 
  1/2 
  1 
  3/2  
  2 
  5/2 
  3
```

Is there any function or script which can give result like this?

Idea is to create result based onMinimum boundary (MinFomrat col value which is integer) to Maximum boundary (MaxFormat Col value which is integer) accordingly to the precision value.

Hence, in above example, value should start from -2 and generate the next values based on the precision value (1/2) till it comes to 3

Comment: should it start with `-2` rathern than `2` ??

Comment: What are you actually selecting?

Comment: a bit harsh with all the downvotes. Seems to be a straight forward question to me

Comment: Should it not end with `6` in addition to starting with `-2`?

Comment: might be a strainght forward question but not a straight forward answer. :)

Comment: @Squirrel I agree, but isn't that a nice change from the daily "how to use rownumber and pivot" standard questions ?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk. LOL. For that instead of the usual pivot question, we should up-void this :)

Comment: idea is to create a result based on Minimum boundary (MinFormat) to Maximum boundary (MaxFormat) accordingly to the precision value.

Comment: @Mark yes it should start with -2

Comment: Just voted to re-open... I'm with @t-clausen.dk that this question isn't that bad. SO police sometimes shoots before asking :-) And one question to the OP: Which values are there in "Precision"? Why is this not a `DECIMAL` or `FLOAT`? What happens, if the chain of steps does not hit the upper border exactly?

Comment: @Shnugo the values in precision can be  1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, 1/32, 1/64 only. and the values in Min/Max format will always be integer.

Comment: @Shnugo And chain of steps can hit to exact closest value to that upper border if its not hitting to exact value

Comment: @omkarpatade with those fractions it will always hit the upper border

Comment: My answer is ready (and I'm probably not the only one :-) ) Waiting for re-opening...

Comment: mine is ready too . . . and the result is in fraction :) Wonder how Rusian post the answer ....

Comment: @Squirrel I'm puzzled too... Is it possible, that - if you've loaded the page *before* it was put on hold, that the answer button is still active and working?

Comment: not sure . .. maybe . .

Comment: @Squirrel  How to re-open the question? Any action required from my side?

Comment: Mine is also ready, although using the described fractions hardcoded. Betting I have the shortest solution

Comment: @omkarpatade `to reopen a closed question, five (5) people with at least 3000 reputation must agree that the question is suitable for the site and cast votes to reopen the question. `

Comment: I am assuming that you want 2/4 written as 1/2. If you have some contact information. I could mail the query

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Could you mail the query on omkar5online@yahoo.co.in

Comment: @t-clausen.dk, bettern than private eMail was to open a new question, wasn't it? Omkar, just open a new question and place a link here as a comment. Everybody with an answer will pop up there in seconds :-)

Comment: @Shnugo that could be an option, I just feared it would be closed as a duplicate

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Oh yes, the SO police. But we will be faster :-)

Comment: @Shnugo to be honest, I am very curious how other people solved it

Comment: @t-clausen.dk  Me too... Anybody with SO friends over 3000? Just ask them to re-open this silly thing ...

Comment: @t-clausen.dk i have created new question for this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36549284/sql-2008-query-to-get-result-in-fraction-format

Comment: @Shnugo can you post your answer on this link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36549284/sql-2008-query-to-get-result-in-fraction-format

Comment: @omkarpatade sorry, I had to rush off. Will answer in about 2 hours ...

Comment: OK, this is now a little funny, but I vote to close this as duplicate, as this question together with an already accepted answer exists twice on SO

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte as
(
    SELECT CAST(MinFormat as float) as data, MaxFormat, CAST(Precision as float) as Precision
        FROM (VALUES (-2, 3, N'0.5')) as your_table(MinFormat, MaxFormat, Precision)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST((data + Precision) as float) as data, MaxFormat, Precision
        FROM cte
        WHERE data + Precision <= MaxFormat
)
SELECT data FROM cte ORDER BY data OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```